# warning: for system() in c++

Tags: c++, imagemagick

I have one c++ program
I am calling `ImageMagick command` through `system();` function
Its working for some simple commands
But when I am calling this command

```
sprintf(command, "convert -threshold 25% f1/file%.3d.png f2/file%.3d.png", num,num);
system(command);
```

Its giving me warning saying

```
warning: format ‘% f’ expects type ‘double’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’
```

I know because of `%` in command 25`% f`1 is having different meaning
Please help me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to write `25%%` instead of `25%.` to escape the '%' sign.

Answer (score 3):

Use `%%` if you need to include the `%` character:

```
sprintf(command, "convert -threshold 25%% f1/file%.3d.png f2/file%.3d.png", num,num);
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to obtain literal percent sign one needs to write `%%`, i.e. in your case:

```
sprintf(command, "convert -threshold 25%% f1/file%.3d.png f2/file%.3d.png", num,num);
```